# PHP clone keyword vs clone() command line CLI issues

Tags: oop, php

I have been using the clone keyword to duplicate objects like so:

```
$x = clone $obj;
```

as per [the manual](http://php.net/language.oop5.cloning).

This works fine when accessed by browser. `phpinfo()` reports PHP version 5.2.6.

However when run by cron or from the CLI I get

> "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE"

from the clone keyword.

`php -v` reports PHP 4.4.9 (cli)

Is this error from a version conflict?

If I use `clone()` in my scripts like so:

```
$_SESSION['user'] = clone($userObject);
```

I get odd intermittent problems with the `$_SESSION['user']` which do not occur when using the clone keyword.

Does this make any sense to anyone?

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the server has 4 and 5 installed and the CLI reports 4.4.9 simply due to PATH order:

From support:

"Running the "php -v" command in the shell will always return V4.  That's because we have two separate installs for PHP on your server.  One for V4 and one for V5, and the PHP 4 interpreter shows up in your PATH environment variable first.  If you'd like to use V5 through the shell you'll need to be sure to use the full path"

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the `clone $foo` keyword is only available on PHP 5 and newer.

Also, if you're still using PHP 4.4.9, that may be a bigger problem.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.

When not running CLI the version is 5.2.6.

What is the latest CLI version?  I was just looking at php.net and I can't tell.

Comment: PHP versions are the same for both CGI and CLI - they're just invoked differently, but with the same core. (I think the latest is PHP 5.2.9-2, at least I'm using it right now.)